# JToken.ToObject giving same value again and again

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following method..

```
public void Handle(JToken jsonTable)
    {
        var myvar = jsonTable.ToObject<abcTable>();
        // other code
    }
```

abcTable structure:

```
public class abcTable
    {
        public string Column1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
       public string Column2
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public bool Column3
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

}
```

When I call Handle method-- jsontable has Column1="a" and Column2="b" and Column3 is not present.....

After going through .ToObject(), myvar gets Column3 = false along with the other two values

I need Column3 = null after the object is formed..

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `Column3` cannot be null because `bool` is a value type. You could make it `bool?`, but even then your question isn't really clear. Can you give an example of the JSON you are processing and the expected output?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks, bool? solved the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, bool can not be set to null. Any variable you create as type `bool` will automatically be set `false` and not `null`. To create a boolean that can be set to null, use the nullable type `bool?`.

```
public bool? Column3
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Now you can set Column3 like you would normally do:

```
Column3 = true;
```

Getting the value is a bit more trivial:

```
if (Column3.HasValue) // Check if Column3 is not null
{
    boo value = Column3.Value;
    // process the value here
}
```